# Circuit to Detect State of Output Pin

Tags: digital-logic, mosfet

I am trying to implement a circuit using mosfets that will detect the state of a pin with 2 outputs. The input (I) to output (O) relationship I want is this:

[image]

Comment: I'm guessing you're driving a motor and want forward, reverse and stop ... but only have one control pin?

Comment: No trying to turn on some LEDs

Comment: So you want a circuit that if it's connected to nothing or to a 3-stated output both of its LEDs will be OFF, if it's connected to a logic high one of the LEDs will Go ON, and if it's connected to a logic low the other LED will go ON?  And what's the deal with the MOSFETS? Wouldn't it be OK if it used a couple of voltage comparators?

Comment: Yes. I had a friend ask me to do it with just Mosfets and build a circuit that burns 0 power when in highZ.

Comment: Still an H bridge. It won't go high Z, but both sides will be at the same potential meaning that no current will flow.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams It is unclear to me how would you make an H bridge draw zero power when in an "intermediate" state.

Comment: @Gonzik; If you add "@EM Fields" when you reply to my comments, the system will ping me and I won't have to try to remember to come back here randomly to find what's going on. Thanks. :-)

Comment: @Dzarda: Using MOSFETs means that only leakage current flows when both sides are at the same potential. But the same could be said for anything at high Z.

Comment: @Goznik It would be vastly more useful if you would put the "extra" information that is extremely relevant into the question initially and highly more useful if you would add it to the question - perhaps as an "added" footnote  if it comes to light under torture long the way. Also, it would be good to know if you mean essentially zero power - ay under 1 microamp quiescent, or really really close to zero power (nano amps) or eg "nicely low" eg 10's or 100's or ... of uA would be good. And you start off posing it as and output requirement problem and end up as a LED drive one which MAY shift ...

Comment: ... where the reference is allowed to be, but also may not. eg with LEDs one output may be on relative to V+ and the other relative to ground, OR you might need (have to have) both relative to ground - so EMFields answer would not suit (even though trivially adaptable) or ... . | And efficiency when on is also of interest. If low power LEDs then some clever things can be done with low energy efficiency. | And may the input drive supply the LED current? | What vooltage supply? | Any specific LEDs in mind ? | And ... ie the more information given the better the answers may be (sometimes :-) )..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The circuit below simulates nicely.

Vcc is the supply voltage for the logic family being probed, Vin goes to the node being probed, and 0V goes to ground.

The logic thresholds are set with R4, R5, and R7, and I've set them for Voh(min) = 3V and Vol(max) = 2V with a 5V supply.

The LTspice circuit list is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qh3ae74ithmzgb5/3-state%20probe.asc?dl=0) if you want to play with the circuit

[image]

Comment: Thanks @EM Fields. I think that has me on the right track to figure it out with FETs.

Answer (score 1):

This circuit has worked for me in the past when I needed to drive a bi-colour LED off a single microcontroller pin, but would work equally well (if not better) for 2 individual LEDs. It requires a rail-to-rail-output opamp to work properly.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJINZm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When the pin is set to Hi-Z, both inputs to the opamp are at Vcc/2, and its output is also also set to Vcc/2, so neither LED lights.
When the input is driven to 0, the opamp's (-) input is driven to 0, while its (+) input remains at roughly Vcc/2. Its output therefore swings high and causes D2 to light up.
When the input is driven to 1 (Vcc), the opamp's (-) input follows, while (+) still stays at roughly Vcc/2. So the output now swings low and D1 lights up instead.

Answer (score 0):

> I had a friend ask me to do it with just 
>   Mosfets and build a circuit that burns 
>   0 power when in highZ

I'd use high end switch (p-channel) for one LED and low end switch (n-channel) for another LED. Connect the inputs of the switches through two Zener diodes. The Zener voltages should be greater than half voltage of the circuit and should be less than full voltage of the circuit (subtracted mosfet gate voltage). Apply input between the Zeners. (Add resistors between gates and sources for mosfets)

With no input current the voltage on the connection between Zeners is half voltage of the circuit, then current through zeners is zero, mosfets are closed. When the input is either high or low, one Zener opens, it's mosfet opens.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you say you want, in the fine print, rather than the significantly different requirement in the question, this may meet your need.

Both are true zero power apart fromleakage when tri-state.

The left hand circuit draws LED power from the input drive.

The right hand circuit is more conventional.
Greatest Iq (offstate current) is probably zener leakage.
As per notes, Vzener is > V+/2 - higher the better subject to having enough drive voltage.

Use of MOSFETs with low Vgsth allows shorting R0 and removal of RL1, RU1 and well under 1 uA quiescent current drain. (2 x transistor off-state leakage in series with LEDs.

For minimum parts count and some viewer confusion, careful choice of FET for Q1, Q2 and zener voltage allows shorting of LED drive resistors, with FETs acting as rough current sources.

[image]